indenting a whole minipage including its footnotes
Following Indenting a whole paragraph I am trying to indent a whole paragraph in a minipage (I use the latter because I want to control the fontsize and actually use some more commands inside, that do not matter to this MWE).
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{0.88\linewidth}\small \setlength{\leftskip}{4mm}
        [{CITATION}]{Here are some reasons to quote from your sources:\footnote{\,Section 6.3 adapted from: \emph{The Skidmore Guide to Writing}, section on Documentation and Plagiarism.} 
            
            \textbf{To provide support.} Cite as an appeal to authority, to bring the voices
            of experts into your paper. 
            
            \textbf{To use vivid language.} Cite because the wording of the original source is
            clearer and more effective than any paraphrase you could write. 
            
            \textbf{To represent the source fairly.} When you quote accurately and directly,
            no one can claim that you have misrepresented the source. 
            
            \textbf{To enrich an argument.} Cite to interject controversy, for example, and
            show what's at stake in taking a position.}
    \end{minipage}
    \setlength{\leftskip}{0mm}
\end{document}

The problem is: the footnote does not follow the indentation.
Question: How to get the footnote at the bottom of the minipage to also use the same identation?

remove the \leftskip setting (which isn't really ever supported in LaTeX) your whole minipage is already indented by \parindent  but if you want it further to the right use for example
\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}{0.88\linewidth}
...

then it will be flush with the right margin so the whole mini pag eincluding its footnotes will be indented by .12\textwidth
